# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call, Dirac function for an intervall of values Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a simple function that returns 1 for a certain value, here 0.

But I keep getting this error:

```
Diracx(i) = 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Can you please help?

```
def Dirac(x):
    Diracx = np.zeros(size(x))
    for i in range(size(x)):
        if (x(i) == 0):
            Diracx(i) = 1    

    return Diracx 


plt.plot(x,DiracDelta(x))
```

Comment: You want Diracx[i] = 1 (square brackets) -- it's an array.

Comment: This question isn't really about Dirac functions. It's about `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if only to spur someone else to offer a better answer.

```
>>> x = np.array([-2,-1,0,1,2])
>>> a = np.zeros(np.size(x))
>>> a[x!=0]=1
>>> a
array([ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.])
```

Comment: hum.. It is actually easier ! Thank you Sir. I have a question though, when I do so, or like my example I don't really get an impulse at one value and 0 at others but I get o sort of interpolation. How can I turn off this interpolation ? I used plt.plot(x,a) to plot

Comment: Then I think you need to (a) approximate the Dirac function by one that is mid-way close to the Dirac and far away from a triangle, and (b) plot more points so that the pulse is displayed more clearly.